# How To Do Two Times String Charachets Replace/Remove at Once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text string which is like "1,000 kW" as

```
var result = "1,000 kW"
```

can you please let me know how I can clean it to only display 1000 on one line? I already tried the replace() as:

```
 var res1 = result.replace(',','');
 var res2 = res1.replace(' kw','');
 alert(res2);
```

which is working but I need to have the code in one line. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex to replace everything that's not numbers with nothing

```
var res1 = result.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gXzuy/4/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo but can you please give me an idea how does the (/\D/g,'') doing the job?

Comment: `\D` mathes any character that is not numeric, `g` means global, and then we just replace everything but the numbers with nothing.

Comment: It also takes care of international numeric characters like 六, right?

Comment: @JoeFrambach - Not sure, it doesn't when I test it, but maybe in other languages it somehow does. `\d` means "digit", and uppercasing is opposite, so `\D` means "not digit", and what a "digit" is, I don't know, always thought it was just `0-9`, and for me it is, I don't speak chinese, arabic or any other language with such characters ?

Comment: Ah, it is perl where `\d` is locale-aware and unicode-aware. Carry on.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = "1,000 kW"
var res1 = result.replace(/,|( kW)/g,'');
console.log(res1); // outputs 1000;
```